# Angular AoT Compilation

Tags: angular, angular-universal, angular-aot

I was going through updated Angular docs and have found that they have changed their approach now.
Earlier it was as follows:

1. run `ng eject` command to generate webpack.config.js.
2. create webpack.config.aot.js, main-aot.ts, tsconfig-aot.json, index-aot.html with seperate code for aot.

Now, they are doing using rollup and system.js.

Is there any specific reason behind this?
and for server side rendering as well it mentioned to use webpack.
Why not use webpack for both?
It is also mentioned that angular-cli uses webpack under the hood then why is there a need to use system.js?

Answer (score 1):

**Webpack vs Rollup**

Webpack produced a slightly bigger bundle than Rollup.

This difference can be explained by some extra overhead added by Webpack to each bundled module.

Webpack wraps every module in a new function scope
whereas Rollup puts everything in a single function scope

Another difference is that Rollup supports **Tree Shaking.**

Tree Shaking is the process of ensuring that unused code is not included in the bundle. In this case that means omitting any unused code from the Angular framework.

Still, before we judge Webpack, it's important to point out that Webpack is much more feature rich than Rollup.

Webpack makes up for the slightly bigger bundle size with more flexibility. One example of this is code splitting which can be used for lazy loading.

Rollup does not support code splitting, so you are limited to a single file bundle. This might become an issue as your application grows beyond what is practical as a single file download. Webpack will let you split the bundle into multiple files and lazy load on demand.

**AOT vs JIT**

With AOT, the compiler runs once at build time using one set of libraries; with JIT it runs every time for every user at runtime using a different set of libraries

When using angular-cli in development `--aot` flag is set to `false` by default, while `true` in production.

AOT compilation and tree shaking take more time than is practical for development. So, it's best to **JIT compile in development** and switch to **AOT compilation before deploying to production.**

**Use of SystemJS**

The **JIT version relies on SystemJS** to load individual modules. Its scripts appear in its index.html.

The AOT version loads the entire application in a single script, aot/dist/build.js. It does not need SystemJS, so that script is absent from its index.html

**Why not use webpack for both?**

**Answer:** Because we want to support Tree shaking, taking advantage of the ingenious design of ES2015 modules and have smaller bundle in production. While in development we are less worried about the bundle size, in and server side rendering code-splitting is a much hairier problem, Rollup doesn’t support it. Similarly, Rollup doesn’t do hot module replacement (HMR),some things just don’t translate to ES2015, whereas webpack handles everything you throw at it with aplomb.

Note: Not only Angular, but Ember, React and Vue are also using Rollup for building in production.

References: [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler),

[Webpack vs Rollup](https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-and-rollup-the-same-but-different-a41ad427058c)